# WndProc alternative in xamarin

Tags: winforms, xamarin.forms

Am new to Xamarin-forms and c# and I want to convert this function to its best alternative in Xamarin-forms to complete my code please help me and  am still learning.
This the function override from `winforms form` class but `winforms form` is not supported in Xamarin-forms so I want its best alternative or hack arroud it:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{

}
```

Please kindly help me out.

Comment: WndProc has no equivalent function in Forms.  It only applies to W32

Comment: Xamarin and WinForms are nothing alike. Take everything you know about WinForms and throw it out the door because very little of it (if any) will apply in Xamarin.